# using rmic in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi, stub, netbeans6.5

I have written rmi server code in netbeans 6.5. How can I use rmic in netbeans 6.5 so that I can create server_stub class?

Comment: I have added the tags- netbeans and netbeans 6.5, since it relates to both.

Comment: Its a bad idea, and would result in too many tags in future. Would be hard for the person who will be looking for an answer. Reverting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Spring's** remote proxying (`RmiProxyfactoryBean`), you don't need to generate any stub/skel classes at all. Spring just does all the magic for you behind the scenes. You don't even need to implement the `Remote` interface!

See [the docs here](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html#remoting-rmi)

Comment: The standard RMI implementation also provides a proxy implementation, if you call UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote, port).

Comment: Yes - but in Spring you can export anything; even interfaces which don't implement Remote

Answer (score 0):

Why not edit the standard build.xml located in the project root directory? Include the [Rmic](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rmic.html) Ant task. This will automatically rmic your classes every time you build a project in netbeans.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use rmic through netbeans. you need to generate the server stub manually by running the rmic command at the command line. but in case of eclipse you can generate the stub from the ide with the help of rmi plugin.

Comment: Not from NetBeans itself. But one can change the build.xml file. If you know ant this should be a breeze.

Answer (score -2):

You have to insert the below code into your build.xml file.

> ```
> <target name="startRMI" depends="init">
>     <exec executable="rmiregistry" dir="${build.classes.dir}">
>     </exec>
> </target>
> ```

Then right click -> build.xml -> Run target -> Other targets -> startRMI

This will start the RMI registry.