# plugin to generate stub file

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, rmi, stub

Is there a plugin for netbeans that can generate a stub ? If there is please link it in the answer.

If there isn't please tell me the way i can generate stub file with netbeans.

Comment: what kind of stub? Stub for web service? RMI? Anything else?

Comment: Take a look on this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067499/using-rmic-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

You haven't needed a stub in RMI for about 7 years. See the preamble to the Javadoc for UnicastRemoteObject.